# While using google maps in a xamarin project getting the error "Please install package: 'GPS Maps' available in SDK installer"

Tags: xamarin.android

While using google maps in a xamarin project getting the error "Please install package: 'GPS Maps' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\neha.ghosh\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\embedded./ doesn't exist"

Comment: Hi Neha, and welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.
Take your time to format and rephrase your question please. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Install Google Repository and Google Repository Services.  And also try the solutions foundv [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46844/please-install-package-gps-appindexing-in-the-sdk-installer)